# Xcode 9 crashes when trying to record automation in Safari

Tags: ios, automated-tests, xcode9, xcuitest

As the title says, i'm trying to record test automation steps for XCUITest in Xcode 9 in Safari browser. Our app has some links it opens in external browser and we need to test some elements on the opening webpage.

But whenever I tried to record steps with Xcode and Safari opens, I tap some of the webpage elements and Xcode crashes.

Any help how to get this working? I'm aware of new automation features in Xcode 9 that promise multi-app testing.

Comment: I'm having the same. I reported that bug to Apple and they said they are aware of the issue. But no word on when they plan to resolve this.

Comment: Crashing with Xcode 9.2 trying to record a UI test on an iPhone X.

Comment: @BadmintonCat Did you find the solution for this?